# Restar columnas de diferentes tablas

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Compañer@s, tengo esta dua ya que mi logica no me esta dando.

Este mi query:

```
(select count(distinct (case when  sno_personalnomina.codnom::int in (1,2,3,5,6,7,8) then sno_personalnomina.codper end)) as sin_renumeracion from sno_personalnomina  inner join sno_nomina on sno_nomina.codnom=sno_personalnomina.codnom WHERE sno_personalnomina.codnom::int in (1,2,3,5,6,7,8) and sno_personalnomina.staper::int=1   GROUP BY sno_personalnomina.codnom, sno_nomina.desnom)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero restarlo con este query

```
select count(distinct (case when sno_hpersonalnomina.codban = '001' then sno_hsalida.codper end)) as trabajadores_tes FROM sno_hpersonalnomina 
left join scb_banco on sno_hpersonalnomina.codban = scb_banco.codban 
inner JOIN sno_hsalida ON sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom = sno_hsalida.codnom AND sno_hpersonalnomina.codper = sno_hsalida.codper AND 
sno_hpersonalnomina.codperi= sno_hsalida.codperi 
inner join sno_nomina on sno_nomina.codnom=sno_hsalida.codnom
WHERE sno_hpersonalnomina.codperi::int=1 AND sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom::integer in (1,2,3,5,6,7,8) and sno_hpersonalnomina.staper::int=1
group by sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago? he intentando usar una suma condicional con case pero no me da los resultados. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Los resultados de las consultas tienen una sola columna. Hace falta una segunda columna o campo para compararlos dos resultados. Me explico, cada consulta puede funcionar como una tabla, la primera consulta sería la tabla1 y la segunda consulta la tabla2. Digamos que el resultado estas usando actualmente es el campo2 de cada tabla y te falta definir el campo1.
La consulta la puedes hacer así:

```
select tabla1.campo1, tabla1.campo2,tabla2.campo2,tabla1.campo2-tabla2.campo2
from tabla1,tabla2
where tabla1.campo1=tabla2.campo1
```

Más específicamente usando tus consultas

```
select tabla1.campo1, tabla1.campo2,tabla2.campo2,tabla1.campo2-tabla2.campo2
    from (select count(distinct (case when  sno_personalnomina.codnom::int in (1,2,3,5,6,7,8) then sno_personalnomina.codper end)) as sin_renumeracion from sno_personalnomina  inner join sno_nomina on sno_nomina.codnom=sno_personalnomina.codnom WHERE sno_personalnomina.codnom::int in (1,2,3,5,6,7,8) and sno_personalnomina.staper::int=1   GROUP BY sno_personalnomina.codnom, sno_nomina.desnom) as tabla1,
    (select count(distinct (case when sno_hpersonalnomina.codban = '001' then sno_hsalida.codper end)) as trabajadores_tes FROM sno_hpersonalnomina 
left join scb_banco on sno_hpersonalnomina.codban = scb_banco.codban 
inner JOIN sno_hsalida ON sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom = sno_hsalida.codnom AND sno_hpersonalnomina.codper = sno_hsalida.codper AND 
sno_hpersonalnomina.codperi= sno_hsalida.codperi 
inner join sno_nomina on sno_nomina.codnom=sno_hsalida.codnom
WHERE sno_hpersonalnomina.codperi::int=1 AND sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom::integer in (1,2,3,5,6,7,8) and sno_hpersonalnomina.staper::int=1
group by sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom)as tabla2
    where tabla1.campo1=tabla2.campo1
```

Por cierto tus consultas me recuerdan al SIGESP, sistema de administracion usado en varios entes públicos de mi país

Comment: Gracias emilio, si, esa consulta es d una bd d ese sistema soy d venezuela